# É possível enviar dados da view tipada com IEnumerable para o Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Eu estou enviando dados usando um get e recebendo no controller usando uma QueryString, o problema é que o valor vai em um formato sem as casas decimais, então quando tenho um valor tipo 10,20, esta enviando apenas 1020 gravando errado o valor.

```html
@model IEnumerable<Generico.Dominio.TB_JOGO_DETALHE_TEMP>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@Html.Partial("_navbarInterno")
@Html.Partial("_PartialMensagens")




@using (Html.BeginForm("GravarDados", "Aposta", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="container droppedHover">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-prepend input-append">
                <input class="form-control input-sm " onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);" id="numero" name="numero"  placeholder="número.." maxlength="4" type="text"/>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" type="number"  id="valor" name="valor" placeholder="valor.."/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block " type="submit" >Adicionar</button>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você envia os dados da views para o controller através de método GET como está na pergunta, no momento de receber o resultado, eu devo receber exatamente como ele vem é não fazer uma conversão do valor:

Enviado o valor 10,20

estava sendo feito assim:

```
decimal valor = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.QueryString["valor"]);
```

resposta : 1020

mas se eu receber o resultado em uma string, eu vou ter o resultado no mesmo formado digitado:

```
string valor = Request.QueryString["valor"];
```

resposta : 10.20

No momento de gravar no banco eu preciso fazer o tratamento da seguinte forma:

```
string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, " {0:0.00}, ", VALOR_JOGO);
```

isso resolve o problema .

Answer (score 1):

Instale o pacote [DecimalModelBinder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DecimalModelBinder/).

Em `Global.asax.cs`, método `Application_Start`, adicione o seguinte:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal?), new DecimalModelBinder());
```

Ao enviar qualquer tipo de dado decimal para seu *Controller*, a classe utilizada para tratar o valor enviado será a `DecimalModelBinder`. A classe já verifica qual o separador de decimais usado pela cultura configurada no projeto e faz tudo sozinha.

Comment: Poderia me dizer como isso pode resolver o problema?, eu só quero enviar os dados da forma que esta no input

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.